# Hibernate query on embeddable

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

here's the problem:
I want to withdraw a list of UserDomains from database with a method:

```
@Query("SELECT dom FROM User usr JOIN usr.domains dom")
List<UserDomain> findDomains();
```

here is my entity and embeddable class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "usr_id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "usr_username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "usr_password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "usr_email")
private String email;

@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name = "user_domains", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "udo_usr_id"))
private Set<UserDomain> domains;


@Embeddable
public class UserDomain {

@Column(name = "udo_dom_guid")
private String domGuid;

@Column(name = "udo_company_guid")
private String companyGuid;
```

the problem is when I'm trying to execute the query within GET method I'm getting an error:

> "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"

I've been trying to solve this for many hours :( thanks in advance

Comment: If you use a relationship to embeddable and `@ElementCollection`, shouldn't you use `@CollectionTable` instead of `@JoinTable`? And you could set show_sql to true, to check what query is generated by hibernate.

Comment: Also, why use Embeddable in this case, and not another entity?

Comment: And if you *do* use an `@ElementCollection`, then you should not need to use a `JOIN` in your JQL query.  Like an individual primitive or or `@Embeddable` field value, an `@ElementCollection` is an inherent part of the entity on which it is declared.

Comment: These technologies are new for me, sorry if I'm doing silly mistakes. Im not using another entity, because I'm trying to solve a task which I've received in work - it's very similiar to what I've posted. Hibernate is generating query: 'select domains1_.usr_id as col_0_0_ from public.users user0_ inner join user_domains domains1_ on user0_.usr_id=domains1_.udo_usr_id'. After removing JOIN from query I've received exception: 'org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity'